# How to obtain this measurment result for arbitrary qubits in $X$ basis?

Tags: quantum-state, measurement, linear-algebra

I have seen the following claim. Suppose one has two qubits $\vert\psi\rangle = a\vert 0\rangle + b\vert 1\rangle$ and $\vert\phi\rangle =a'\vert 0\rangle + b'\vert 1\rangle$ and both are measured in the $X$ basis. Then, the post-measurement state is

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\psi\rangle|\phi\rangle+(-1)^M|\bar{\psi}\rangle|\bar{\phi}\rangle\right),$$

where $\vert \bar{A}\rangle = X\vert A\rangle$ and $M$ is the measurement outcome of $0$ or $1$ (the product of the two individual measurements).

How does one see this? I tried expanding the two qubit state in the Hadamard basis and have a giant mess of coefficients. I guess there is a quick way to "see" this and would like to know how!

Also, is this a general trick that works for any measurement basis (not just $X$)?

Comment: Yes, it works for any unitary $U$ and the measurement in the eigenbasis of $U$. Two things you can do are: 1) The result holds even for a single qubit and is easier to compute so forget about $\vert\phi\rangle$. 2) The idea is that $U = \vert U_0\rangle\langle U_0\vert - \vert U_1\rangle\langle U_1\vert$ where $\vert U_i\rangle$ are the eigenstates of the operator $U$ and you use this to compute $\vert \bar{\psi}\rangle$. The rest is just collecting terms and expressing everything in the $\vert U_i\rangle$ basis.